# 3V Air Pump loses force when drived by a TIP120 transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors

I'm doing a project driving a 3V air pump motor with a TIP120 transistor connected to an Arduino board.

The schematic is the following:

[image]

When I connect the motor directly to the battery it has almost 50% more force than when it is connected to the transistor.
Anyone knows why this is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: The answer by Elliot explains well why you lose power, I'll just add a popular link that tells the same thing: TIP120 is a very old part that shouldn't be used today https://web.archive.org/web/20161031154742/http://sensitiveresearch.com/DoNotTIP/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TIP120 is a **Darlington** transistor, which implies that it has very high current gain, but it also has a high \$V_{CE}\$ when in saturation. The OnSemi [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF) specifies a \$V_{CESAT}\$ of 2.0V when passing 3A, so most of the voltage available from your 3V source is appearing across the transistor and less is available to drive the motor.

You would be better off using a regular NPN transistor with a low saturation voltage, or an NMOS transistor with a low \$R_{DS}\$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'll try a regular NPN transistor.

Comment: UPDATE: Replaced the TIP with a MOSFET IRF540N. All good! Thanks a lot!